# What does "|=" mean in Java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Note my question is not regarding `!=` but `|=`

A usage example is [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/GsmSMSDispatcher.java#l107)

I assume that `x |= y` is the same as `x = x | y` but I could not find confirming documentation and wanted to be sure

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a bitwise inclusive or assignment: http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/03.html

Answer (score 7):

It's a bitwise "or" plus assignment, so you are quite correct in your assumption.

Answer (score 3):

More correctly, x |= y is actually computed as x = x | (y).

Here is an interesting example of why this is important.

```
int c = 2;
c %= c++ * ++c;
```

The interesting consequence here is that it would be written as

```
c = c % (c++ * ++c);
```

Java specifications tell us that the JVM will see the initial c first and store it, anything preceding it will have no effect on it, thus c++ & ++c will not actually affect the outcome of the calculation. It will always be c = 2 %  which equals 2 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can read [Java Langauge Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26)

Comment: Thanks, nice to have a spec document