# Syntax/operators Java - What does this line mean?

Tags: java, expression, bitwise-operators

I've found one line in Java like this :

```
result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
```

I've searched about what operators do but I'm still not able to understand what it is supposed to do assuming `result`, `b` and `shift` are integer values.
Could anyone tell me what does this line is supposed to do ?

**Update** - Here is the sample part of the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17007360/2500326)

```
int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
do {
    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
    shift += 5;
} while (b >= 0x20);
```

Comment: You need to provide more context to learn what this is doing. Is the code from here: http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "|=" mean in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420925/what-does-mean-in-java)

Comment: If you know what `&`, `<<` and `|=` does, you should be able to understand what that line does.

Comment: @Adam Burry updated. @Dukeling Yes, of course, I can't get that part in particular : `(b & 0x1f) << shift` even if I have basic knowledge in hexadecimal values and shift operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this explanation might help you:

> A. `(b & 0x1f)`: performs a logical `AND` operation between `b` and
>   `0xf1`. This means: return the last 5 bits of `b`
>
> B. `A << shift`: shifts to the left an amount of `shift` bits the result of
>   `A` operation. This means: shift the last 5 bits of `b` an amount of `shift` bits to the left.
>
> C. `result |= B`: assigns to `result` variable the result of perform a
>   logical `OR` operation between `result` itself and the result of `B`
>   operation. This means: perform a logical `OR` between `result` and the last 5 bits of `b` shifted to the left an amount of `shift` bits, and then assign the result to `result` variable.

Hope it be understandable.

Answer (score 2):

It preserves the last 5 bits of b, left shifts them some amount and ors them into result.

In this case it is reversing the process described here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm

Comment: Thanks for the documentation !