# How does the or-assignment operator (|=) work? (C#)

Tags: c#, refactoring, operators, assignment-operator, compound-assignment

I've seen [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx) and answers [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217762/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-c) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420925/what-does-mean-in-java?rq=1) that try to explain what the |= operator is and how it works, and while it kind of makes sense on a basic level... I don't quite get why or how it accomplishes what it does.

The explanations say that `a |= b` is equivalent to `a = a | b`, but I don't get how it evaluates whether to give `a` the value of itself (`a`) or the value of `b`. From my understanding, "or" means that it *can be* one of two things, but doesn't specify which of the two things it is.

In Visual Studio, I use an extension called Refactoring Essentials, which suggested I replace some of my code with a line with the |= operator, and while the code works with the operator in there, I'm lost as to how it accomplishes it, which is what prompted me to try to research it online (and as a result, ask this question).

My code went from

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel this operation?", "Confirm Cancel", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation, MessageBoxResult.No) == MessageBoxResult.No)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

to

```
e.Cancel |= MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel this operation?", "Confirm Cancel", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation, MessageBoxResult.No) == MessageBoxResult.No;
```

and it still worked. While I would guess that `e.Cancel` is determined based upon the evaluation of `MessageBox.Show(...) == MessageBoxResult.No`, I don't know why the |= operator is needed there. Why not just use a standard assignment (=) operator, as the result of the expression is a boolean and `e.Cancel` takes a boolean? And what about using the conditional (? :) operator? How does |= compare to that (if it even does)?

Comment: Because it's an alternative. If the thing is already canceled (Cancel has true value before showing the MessageBox), than the MessageBox answer is not important. However I'm not a fan of such refactoring results because it's getting really hard to read and understand. :P It looks like an unnecessary overkill.

Comment: @mikes The answer I accepted helped me understand what the operator is all about. I agree about the refactoring thing though. Given how I was perplexed for some time with this one too, this may have been a refactoring I was better off not doing lol. There are some other refactoring choices that the extension gives me that I would never implement in my code because it detracts from the code's readability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`|` is the BITWISE OR operator, it is not a BOOLEAN OR operator.

Suppose you have two 8-bit binary numbers 10110100 and 11000101.

If you bitwise OR them you will get a `1` bit set in the output for each position where a bit is set in the first OR the second input, and a `0` bit where NEITHER of the two input bits are set:

```
10110100 
11000101
--------
11110101
```

That's all there is to it.

As you already know, `x |= y;` is exactly the same as `x = x | y;`.

The final point to note is that `bool` is treated as if it were a one-bit number where `1` = true and `0` = false, for the purposes of `|` and `&` bitwise operations when applied to `bool`.

However, do note that you cannot mix `bool` and `int` bitwise operations. For example, the following will give a compile error:

```
bool t = true;
bool f = false;
int x = t | f; // Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'int'
```

ADDENDUM:

The reason that people use `&=` and `|=` for  `bool` rather than what would seem the more logical (pun intended) `&&=` and `||=` is that the latter two operators don't actually exist!

Comment: So, in context of my code: if `MessageBox.Show(...) == ...` is true and `e.Cancel` is false, the result is still true. And the same if the values are switched (if `e.Cancel` is true and `MessageBox...` is false). And if neither `e.Cancel` nor `MessageBox...` are true, then that's when it's set to false. Okay... now that I've had this nudge, I believe I'm starting to get it now. Sorry if my question seemed a bit dumb, I just never made this conclusion. I honestly kind of forgot that a "bitwise OR" operator is a thing. Thank you for the help!